# Iteration speed and element size

Tags: c++, performance, vector, size

I have a `std::vector` filled with following structures:

```
#define ELEMENTSIZE 8

struct Element {
int value;
char size[ELEMENTSIZE - 4]; //1 char is 1B in size - 4B int
};
```

The size of structure depends on defined elementsize, which makes an array of chars of specified size in the structure.

I am benchmarking an average value of these structures in vector and I would love to know the reason why vector filled with bigger structures in size takes longer to iterate over.

For example vector with 1 000 000 8B structures takes roughly 1,7ms and the same test with 128B structures 12,7ms.

Is that big difference because of cache only? If so, could you explain why? Or is there any other aspect that I can not see?

Answer (score 0):

The structure is 16 times bigger, so it should take 16 times longer to iterate through. Mathematically 12,7/1,7 = 7,47 times more, so it almost matches up mathematically.

Now imagine the structure containing the 128B elements was a structure containing 8B elements, but the same size. Do you see now that it really is 16 times larger?

Answer (score 0):

The OS must bring the larger structures in memory, which may take this path:

- From virtual memory to main-memory (L4)
- From main-memory to L3, and to L2 and L1 till the processor (if needs processing)
- At the L1 or processor level, contents have to be copied around the `iterator` object being used. It largely depends on cache performance.
- Now at each iteration, it depends what operation you are performing with the iterator. If content is being copied, or displayed on screen, some sorting/compression being performed more time (from CPU to L4 if needed) would be required.

If all of this is happening, why would `128`  structure not take more time than a `8` byte structure?

Comment: Well, it sounds logically. But if I look a bit deeper, the vector is contiguous storage in memory. So I suppose, that when I loop over the vector, processor should have next iterations already available in cache. I have a 64x processor and ofc the bigger structure takes more operations to process (lets say 3x more operations),  but why is that delay that big? What am I missing?

Comment: At the hardware level more data will be moved. You cannot say 4 bytes and 4MB copying will take same amount of time.